# API to check SAML assertion

Tags: saml-2.0, openam, opensso, opensaml

I am using OpenAm based SAML api, just wanted to know is their a way I can check if SAML assertion is present before doing :

```
map = SPACSUtils.processResponseForFedlet(request, response);
```

So that I can go for this step only if assertion is present as calling "processResponseForFedlet" more than once throws error.

Comment: Even i am looking for the same steps.Can you describe how you are parsing the response SAML using openAM.Thanks.

Comment: @maali you can check for request.getParameter("SAMLResopnse") if not null